# Is it possible to convert a 32-bit ubuntu installation to 64-bit?

Tags: installation, 64-bit, 32-bit, architecture

As in title, is it possible to convert a 32 bit Ubuntu installation to 64 bit to read additional memory after performing a memory upgrade?